# Understanding Spliterator, Collector and Stream in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, spliterator

I am having trouble understanding the [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) interface in Java 8, especially where it has to do with the [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) and [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) interfaces. My problem is that I simply can't understand `Spliterator` and the `Collector` interfaces yet, and as a result, the `Stream` interface is still somewhat obscure to me.

What exactly is a `Spliterator` and a `Collector`, and how can I use them? If I am willing to write my own `Spliterator` or `Collector` (and probably my own `Stream` in that process), what should I do and not do?

I read some examples scattered around the web, but since everything here is still new and subject to changes, examples and tutorials are still very sparse.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You should almost certainly never have to deal with `Spliterator` as a user; it should only be necessary if you're writing `Collection` types yourself and *also* intending to optimize parallelized operations on them.

For what it's worth, a `Spliterator` is a way of operating over the elements of a collection in a way that it's easy to split off part of the collection, e.g. because you're parallelizing and want one thread to work on one part of the collection, one thread to work on another part, etc.

You should essentially never be saving values of type `Stream` to a variable, either.  `Stream` is sort of like an `Iterator`, in that it's a one-time-use object that you'll almost always use in a fluent chain, as in the Javadoc example:

```
int sum = widgets.stream()
                  .filter(w -> w.getColor() == RED)
                  .mapToInt(w -> w.getWeight())
                  .sum();
```

`Collector` is the most generalized, abstract possible version of a "reduce" operation a la map/reduce; in particular, it needs to support parallelization and finalization steps.  Examples of `Collector`s include:

- summing, e.g. `Collectors.reducing(0, (x, y) -> x + y)`
- StringBuilder appending, e.g. `Collector.of(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::toString)`

Comment: Spliterator(s) also provides a way to stream an Iterable that isn't a Collection

Comment: I meant "a reduce operation, in the sense that term is meant in map/reduce"

Comment: Is `Collectors.of` an old method of beta version that was removed or am-I missing something ? For completeness, `(x,y) -> x+y` can be written as `Integer::sum`.

Comment: Er, no, sorry, it's Collector.of, not Collectors.of.

Comment: Your example of Collector would be more useful if you would explain what each of your Collectors does.

Comment: @Bohemian Could not imagine an example that is Iterable but isn't a collection. Can it be a *generator function*? I need some examples

Comment: Initially pre-Java8, followed a pure OOP paradigm, I don't know, why Java 8 has forced on paradigm shift towards FP. Isn't practicing functional paradigm style with Java 8 looks weird? You design a class hierarchy using OOP principles and then fill the methods using FP style( with Java 8 features). Is that the idea in using Java 8?

Answer (score 92):

`Spliterator` basically means "splittable Iterator".

Single thread can traverse/process the entire Spliterator itself, but the Spliterator also has a method `trySplit()` which will "split off" a section for someone else (typically, another thread) to process -- leaving the current spliterator with less work.

`Collector` combines the specification of a `reduce` function (of map-reduce fame), with an initial value, and a function to combine two results (thus enabling results from Spliterated streams of work, to be combined.)

For example, the most basic Collector would have an initial vaue of 0, add an integer onto an existing result, and would 'combine' two results by adding them. Thus summing a spliterated stream of integers.

See:

- [`Spliterator.trySplit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#trySplit--)
- [`Collector<T,A,R>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html)

Answer (score 5):

Interface [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) - is a core feature of [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

The [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) and [`parallelStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--) default methods are presented in the [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) interface. These methods use the Spliterator through the call to the `spliterator()`:

```
...

default Stream<E> stream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
}

default Stream<E> parallelStream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), true);
}

...
```

Spliterator is an internal iterator that breaks the stream into the smaller parts. These smaller parts can be processed in parallel.

Among other methods, there are two most important to understand the Spliterator:

- [`boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#tryAdvance-java.util.function.Consumer-)
  Unlike the [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), it tries to perform the operation with the next element. 
  If operation executed successfully, the method returns `true`. Otherwise, returns `false` - that means that there is absence of element or end of the stream.
- [`Spliterator<T> trySplit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#trySplit--)
  This method allows to split a set of data into a many smaller sets according to one or another criteria (file size, number of lines, etc).

Comment: ´If operation executed successfully..´ You should probably reword this. [tryAdvance javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#tryAdvance-java.util.function.Consumer-) is clearer: ´If a remaining element exists, performs the given action on it, returning true; else returns false.´

Answer (score 4):

The following are examples of using the predefined collectors to perform common mutable reduction tasks:

```
 // Accumulate names into a List
 List<String> list = people.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());

 // Accumulate names into a TreeSet
 Set<String> set = people.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));

 // Convert elements to strings and concatenate them, separated by commas
 String joined = things.stream()
                       .map(Object::toString)
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

 // Compute sum of salaries of employee
 int total = employees.stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Employee::getSalary)));

 // Group employees by department
 Map<Department, List<Employee>> byDept
     = employees.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment));

 // Compute sum of salaries by department
 Map<Department, Integer> totalByDept
     = employees.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment,
                                               Collectors.summingInt(Employee::getSalary)));

 // Partition students into passing and failing
 Map<Boolean, List<Student>> passingFailing =
     students.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s.getGrade() >= PASS_THRESHOLD));
```

Comment: This does not answer the question of the Op, plus there is no explanation or description of your post.