# Best type of iterator to return for a collection? Spliterator, Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a service layer with many methods returning collection of (usually lots) objects. Those collections are only meant to be iterated over (eventually in parallel).

What is the best / usual return type to use?

- `Spliterator<T>`
- `Stream<T>`

Comment: Implement `Iterable<T>`. If desired, override `.spitterator()`.

Comment: Return neither, according to [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19235863/642706).

Comment: Well, the answer you mention is not clear on that: what to use instead? Returning a `Collection<T>` is out of question in my context. And I need to allow the user to parallelize processing on elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the calling part is only going to iterate through it (map, filter...), you should prefer Stream, since Stream has these built-in function already and there's no need to materialize a specific collection.... let the caller materialize the stream if he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of them. Return [`Iterable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) that stands on the top of the collections hierarchy and is qualified for the iteration.

> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the "for-each loop" statement. See For-each Loop

The purpose of the mentioned classes is a bit different:

- [`Spliterator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) is an object for traversing and partitioning elements of a source but it doesn't represent a source (a collection) itself. Each `Iterable` has a method that returns `Spliterator`.
- [`Stream<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) is a sequence of elements. Its purpose is process elements until the terminal operation is called. This is not as useful as a source. To create a parallel stream from `Spliterator` use

  ```
  StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
  ```

The point is that everything mentioned above in the list can be created from `Iterable<T>` that should be used as a source.

Comment: You mean return `Iterator<T>` I suppose? Well, in that case it's a big performance hit. For example, using `Streams::stream(Iterator<T>)` to convert back to a stream will lose size information. So the `count()` reduce method need to iterate over all the sequence. Same for other parallel iterations.

Comment: I didn't mean `Iterator` but `Iterable`. You said: "Those collections are only meant to be iterated over (eventually in parallel). What is the best / usual return type to use?" - I answered the general question. I see no reason to return either `Stream` or `Spliterator` or any other `*erator`.